# I mistakenly assigned .exe files as .txt, issue resolved but icons won't change.? 

Tags: windows-7, icons

I mistakenly assigned a .exe file with .txt file. All the programs stopped working, but, then I resolved the issue using [Microsoft fixit tool](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9803442).

Now all programs work well, but, still the icons are shown as text files. Please suggest on how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try rebooting your system, logging out completely and logging back in, or at the very least restarting windows explorer?

Answer (score 2):

Rebuild the Windows Icon cache by executing these commands

```
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F 
CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local 
DEL IconCache.db /a 
shutdown /r /f /t 00
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-file-type-icon-windows-7-and-vista/), check over:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \
>   Explorer \ FileExts \ .exe \ UserChoice

If "UserChoice" Key exists, it means your user had overwrite the default .exe files icon.

Deleting this registry key(I mean, the "UserChoice" Key on this registry path) would return automatically(probably after next reboot).